# How can I display a jquery alert message inside a div instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that counts the number of divs inside a page:

```
jQuery(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
                alert( $(".contentMachine").length );
            });

});
```

Now, I want the result of that to appear inside an html div I made:

```
<span class="subtitleMain" id="totalMachines">0</span>
```

How can I put the numbers inside that instead of having the alert box everytime the page loads?

Sorry! I literally just started learning javascript yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#totalMachines").text($(".contentMachine").length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Prior to that you need to get the DOM element using either the id selector or class selector

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#totalMachines").text(' Total ' + $(".contentMachine").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<span class="subtitleMain" id="totalMachines">0</span>
```

If the initial content of `#totalMachines` is empty then you can also use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#totalMachines").append(' Total ' + $(".contentMachine").length)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<div class="contentMachine">1</div>
<span class="subtitleMain" id="totalMachines"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#totalMachines').html('Total: '+$('.contentMachine').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="subtitleMain" id="totalMachines">0</span>
<div class="contentMachine"></div>
<div class="contentMachine"></div>
<div class="contentMachine"></div>
<div class="contentMachine"></div>
```